# Is it possible to take a GET and POST AcceptVerbs to same Controller Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

like below sameple code.

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
   public ActionResult Login()

{

}

Comment: No, you have to declare another `ActionResult Login()` method. one for POST and one for GET

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Your get won't pass any models to the controller, however you login post should.  Or would, normally, if you were doing things correctly :/

Answer (score 3):

> > Is it possible to take a GET and POST AcceptVerbs to same Controller Action in ASP.NET MVC?

No, But if you remove the GET and POST attributes decorated over your actions, then for every post and get request the same action will be called.

If you create a `New Project > ASP.NET MVC 2/3/4 Web Application > Internet Application`.

If you open the AccountController and check you will find this below:

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

This template itself tell that you need to have separate methods one for "POST" and another for "GET".